# What kind of encrypting is this?

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography

so I've been trying to figure out what this is for a while:

MzggMTAgMTA=

is it base64? Or a hash?

It looks so familiar to me but I can't find what it is...

Thanks and sorry if my question is silly, I am a beginner, thank you!

Comment: where do you get this from  ?

Comment: it's from a puzzle I've been trying to solve..

Comment: And how do you know it's something else that is encrypted / hashed / encoded ? Maybe it's simply the string "MzggMTAgMTA="

Comment: (I'll vote to close this question, but just as a side note, things ending with '=' do indeed look like base64 encoded string to me, and there are tons of tools easily available online that will help you try this approach, for less than the time needed to write your question. But of course it doesn't *have to* be base64. Or anything at all.

Comment: Thank you very much, but believe me, I've tried the base64 but the result was kind of confusing for me..So I thought I wasn't right, this is why I asked here. Sorry if it was stupid

Answer (score 2):

My rule of thumb is, if there's a `=` or even two at the end, then it's Base64 encoded. In this case, the decoded message of your text is "38 10 10".

Comment: Yes I figured that out but then there's also this part MkUgMUYgMUEgMTcgMEYgMjQgMUEgMjAgMTQgMUYgMjIgMUEgMjAgMTcgMEYgMTIgMTAgMUYgMTMgMEMgMUQgMEYgMTAgMUQ=. which I have been unable to decode with only Base64

Comment: Decodes to `2E 1F 1A 17 0F 24 1A 20 14 1F 22 1A 20 17 0F 12 10 1F 13 0C 1D 0F 10 1D` which seems to be some hexadecimal code.

Comment: I thought there is no "0F" in hex

Comment: @fryday Just like sometimes the number `7` is written `07`, so sometimes `F` is written `0F` A byte contains 2 hex digits. There is no reason why the first can't be `0`.

Comment: One byte (8 bits) has a value range of 0..255, which is 00 to FF in hexadecimal. Since there are spaces added in your base64 encoded text, it is heavily implied that these are distinct hexadecimal values in this range. But it doesn't translate to printable ASCII.